# plot.glmnet increase size of variable labels

Tags: r, plot, glmnet

Currently I am using the glmnet package to run a lasso regression (which in the example below is being saved to the "fits" variable. Then when I plot the fits variable it comes up properly but the coefficient labels are very small. Any ideas how I can increase the size of these?

Reproducible example below...

```
require(glmnet)

#setup sample DF with 5 variables
set.seed(123)
sampleDF <- data.frame("V1"=rnorm(100,mean=0,sd=.10),"V2"=rnorm(100,mean=0,sd=.10),"V3"=rnorm(100,mean=0,sd=.10),"V4"=rnorm(100,mean=0,sd=.10),"V5"=rnorm(100,mean=0,sd=.10))

#break data into yVector & xMatrix to put into glmnet
yVector <- sampleDF[,1]
xMatrix <- as.matrix(sampleDF[,2:ncol(sampleDF)])

#use k-fold cross validation to find the min lambda
cv.glmmod <- cv.glmnet(xMatrix,yVector,alpha=1,nfolds=nrow(xMatrix),grouped=FALSE)
best_lambda <- cv.glmmod$lambda.min

#run glmnet
fits <- glmnet(xMatrix, yVector, family="gaussian", alpha=1, nlambda=100)

#plot results
plot(fits,label=TRUE,xvar="lambda")
```

Comment: Look into `cex.axis, cex.lab' They are just base R graphical parameters.

Comment: They change the axis text but the coefficient line labels dont seem to change. I am guessing they are put on there from the glmnet package in a different way?

Comment: if you ulook at `plot.glmnet` and then `plotCoef` (3rd last line) it look as if the label size ishard coded

Comment: Ah found it, looks like it is hard coded into the plotCoef command. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As it looks as if the label size is hard coded (and global changes to `cex` will change the other plot features) you can change `plot.glmnet`

```
# copy the plot function
myPlot <- plotCoef

# replace relevant part
body(myPlot)[[14]] <- quote(if (label) {
  nnz = length(which)
  xpos = max(index)
  pos = 4
  if (xvar == "lambda") {
    xpos = min(index)
    pos = 2
  }
  xpos = rep(xpos, nnz)
  ypos = beta[, ncol(beta)]
  text(xpos, ypos, paste(which), pos = pos, ...) # only changed this with ...
})

# copy first level of plot and replace plotCoef  with myPlot
newplotter <- plot.glmnet

body(newplotter)[[3]] <- quote(myPlot(x$beta, lambda = x$lambda, 
                                     df = x$df, dev = x$dev.ratio, 
                                        label = label, xvar = xvar, ...))
```

This should increase the text (note the plot need to be wide enough)

```
newplotter(fits,label=TRUE,xvar="lambda", cex=1.2)
```

[image]

Comment: Great example and plot to show the difference. Also helped me to see how to look inside an existing function and replace the hard coded parts. Thank you.

Comment: youre welcome.( I used `as.list(body(myPlot))` to get the `[[14]]`)

Comment: @TrevorNederlof; rethought this - it is probably easier to defines a new function to draw the labels http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30560689/adding-labels-on-curves-in-glmnet-plot-in-r