# Legend label errors with glmnet plot in R

Tags: r, plot, glmnet

I modified the function from this post ( [Adding labels on curves in glmnet plot in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30560689/adding-labels-on-curves-in-glmnet-plot-in-r) ) to add legend to the plot as follows:

```
library(glmnet)
fit = glmnet(as.matrix(mtcars[-1]), mtcars[,1])

lbs_fun <- function(fit, ...) {
        L <- length(fit$lambda)
        x <- log(fit$lambda[L])
        y <- fit$beta[, L]
        labs <- names(y)
        text(x, y, labels=labs, ...)
        legend('topright', legend=labs, col=1:length(labs), lty=1) # <<< ADDED BY ME
}
plot(fit, xvar="lambda")
lbs_fun(fit)
```

[image]

However, I am getting mismatch between text labels on plot and in legend. The variable 'am' is clearly incorrectly colored. Where is the error? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 5):

`plot(fit, xvar="lambda")` utilizes the function `matplot`. By default, `matplot` uses 6 colors and recycles them. So you have to create the legend accordingly:

```
lbs_fun <- function(fit, ...) {
        L <- length(fit$lambda)
        x <- log(fit$lambda[L])
        y <- fit$beta[, L]
        labs <- names(y)
        text(x, y, labels=labs, ...)
        legend('topright', legend=labs, col=1:6, lty=1) # only 6 colors
}
```

[image]

Comment: I think this is labeling colors wrong for me after I have more than 6 variables.

Answer (score 2):

You can specify the colors in the `plot` call to match the colors you've picked for the legend:

```
lbs_fun <- function(fit, ...) {
        L <- length(fit$lambda)
        x <- log(fit$lambda[L])
        y <- fit$beta[, L]
        labs <- names(y)
        text(x, y, labels=labs, ...)
        legend('topright', legend=labs, col=1:length(labs), lty=1) # <<< ADDED BY ME
}
plot(fit, xvar="lambda", col=1:dim(coef(fit))[1])
lbs_fun(fit)
```

[image]